# Error showing up Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

```
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM event", con);
    cmd.Fill(ds, "Table");
```

Getting the same error again and again tried everything

please help

Comment: And `con` is being initialized as?

Comment: SqlConnection con;
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.97;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();

Comment: check my edited answer and do like that must resolve your issue ...missing element in this might be commandtype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try like this , missing element in this might be commandtype which is added in below code and also open connection for databse

```
  SqlConnection sqlcon;
   using(sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Servername;Initial 
       Catalog=Marketing;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
   {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM event", sqlcon);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlcon.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
   }
```

**Note :  used and then disposed all within using statements. which is also added above**

---

do this before calling fill method

```
SqlConnection conn= new 
         SqlConnection("Data Source=Servername;Initial Catalog=Marketing;Integrated Security=SSPI");

SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM event", con);
   cmd.Fill(ds, "Table");
```

Comment: @ Pranay Rana: You do not need to open connection because adapter method fill does that

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(YourConnString);
SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand();

try{ myconn.Open(); }
catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox("Error");}
mycmd.Connection = myconn;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

String sqlStr = "Select * FROM event";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, myconn);
da.Fill(ds);
dt = ds.Tables[0];
```